# CSS hamburger Dropdown using :check not working

Tags: css, menu, dropdown

I am trying to implement a mobile dropdown using a hamburger icon with a checkbox hack I have found several examples of this. Here is one that uses radio with tabs [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paullferguson/Sv54G/3/). I know this is basically this same idea and I have seen other examples on this page [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). The problem is I have tried just about every combination to get it to work and it won't. Could some see if there is something missing in my code? Note I used the word hamburger instead of the character for the glyph since it is not available.

```css
.nav .mobile-bar label:before {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  content: "Hamburger";
  left: 24px;
  color: #000;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label ~ ul {
  display: block;
}
.nav ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 nav">
  <div class="mobile-bar">
    <label for="hamburger">
      <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger">
    </label>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item_has_children"><a href="#">SERVICES</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">WEB SITES</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PRINT GRAPHICS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">VIDEO</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to ***select parent element by pure css***.

Solutions:

**Change the html structure**

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sv54G/325/)

```css
.nav .mobile-bar label:before {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  content: "Hamburger";
  left: 24px;
  color: #000;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
  display: block;
}
.nav ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 nav">
  <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger" />
  <div class="mobile-bar">
    <label for="hamburger">

    </label>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>

    </li>
    <li class="page_item_has_children"><a href="#">SERVICES</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">WEB SITES</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PRINT GRAPHICS</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">VIDEO</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a>

      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sv54G/324/)

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('#hamburger').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('.mobile-bar').toggleClass('selected');
    });
  });
```

```css
.nav .mobile-bar label:before {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  content: "Hamburger";
  left: 24px;
  color: #000;
}
.nav ul {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav .selected + ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 nav">

  <div class="mobile-bar">
    <label for="hamburger">
      <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger" />
    </label>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>

    </li>
    <li class="page_item_has_children"><a href="#">SERVICES</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">WEB SITES</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">PRINT GRAPHICS</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">VIDEO</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a>

      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
input{
  display:none;
}
input:checked + label + ul{
  display:none;
}
label{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:64px;
  height:64px;
}
top,middle,bottom{
  position: absolute;
  background:black;
  width:64px;
  height:12px;
  transition: top 0.2s, transform 0.2s;
}
top{
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  top:0px;
}
middle{
  top:24px;
}
bottom{
  top:48px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
}

input:not(:checked) + label top{
  transform:rotate(55deg);
  top:24px;
}
input:not(:checked) + label bottom{
  transform:rotate(-55deg);
  top:24px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ham" checked="checked" />
<label for="ham">
  <top></top>
  <middle></middle>
  <bottom></bottom>
</label>
<ul>
  <li><a href="www.google.com">Google.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.google.com">Google.com</a></li>
  <li><a href="www.google.com">Google.com</a></li>
</ul>
```